# Using google-youtube web component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, web-component, youtube-javascript-api, google-web-component

Is there anyone who can describe how to use [google-youtube](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-youtube) web component in angular 2, because Official documentaion provides nothing about how to use web component.

any guide/tutorial will be very helpfull, Thanks

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed. Also add error messages if you got some.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i don't know where to start therefore i just installed Google-youtube web component via Bower and injected via script tag in my index.html, that's it